# How to interface QML and Java?

Tags: java, javascript, qt, qml

If QML is used for GUI and Java for developing API for a linux based device,How to interface QML with Java?

Comment: Unless there are existing Qt interfaced on this platform, I'd recommend JavaFx to work with Java (as below).  There seems to be no native method to work the two together, Making a client server with a C++ (or other) front, just seem like you are making it complicated by insiting on Java.

Answer (score 3):

One approach for cross platform integration is using web service. I would probably expose my Java code as a RESTful web service (See [JAX-RS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html)) and invoke it from QML using [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=qml%20xmlhttprequest).

It's also worth mentioning Java GUI library such as swing  / JavaFX has cross platform capability, so it should still run on Linux (and whichever platform runs Java). You might not need to write QML at all

Comment: I need to develop gui with QML(Qt) and interface with java this is my actual target on ARM platform. so could you please provide the ways to this or could you please ways to interface Qt(for GUI as per requirement) and java apart from QTJAMBI, JNI, SWIG Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2):

Possible approaches I can think of are :

1. [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/)
2. [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/)

[ You have mentioned to tell something other than these ]

Other than this :

Use qml for UI and interface it with C++ using Qt-qml bindings. Then expose these C++ interfaces over some IPC common to both Java and C++ ( For eg. expose something on D-Bus using Qt-Dbus and then call these functionality using Java-DBus code  )

Comment: Teh Qt-Jambi link keeps getting blocked by the antimalware filters.