# How to call qml functions from java?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

Hi a have a java class and a function in main.qml file in my qt project. This is my qml function

```
 function request(url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = (function(myxhr) {
                return function() {
                    if(myxhr.readyState === 4) { callback(myxhr); }
                }
            })(xhr);

            xhr.open("GET", url);
            xhr.send();
        }
```

I want to call this function from the java code, but I don't know how to do it. Yes, I can use standart java libraries to make a http request, but I think it isn't necessary to do if I already have the qml function that works.
If I can call java functions from qml or c++ using jni, maybe I can call qml functions from java?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185074/how-to-interface-qml-and-java